# What will happen if I migrate django models directly from the mysql database

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

Earlier i had this as my model class.

```
class Certificate(models.Model):
    User = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

but after few months i added "data field" into my model class directly from the sql and without using migrations.

Now i am just wondering if i change the code in my models and again make migrations, will it work?

```
class Certificate(models.Model):
    User = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    data = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Hello, I think this is better to only deal with the database through django orm to avoid this kind of situation. Maybe try to deploy a simple project to test it and you will see what will happen.

Comment: Probably the migration will fail with `column already exists` error but you can simply skip it by executing `python manage.py migrate your_app --fake`